# To get outline of UIImage image using CIFilter IOS 5.0?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, filtering

I am using iOS 5.0 sdk. In that i want to apply a filter, to get the outline of UIImage. For example [image]

Please let me know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The filter you're looking for is either CIEdgeWork or CILineOverlay, however, neither of them are supported on iOS.

Comment: but both filter are available in OSX only.. you have any other solution?